# How to fix NameError: name 'phrasedocs' is not defined

Tags: python, nlp

I'm working on a classification task, using a movie reviews dataset from Kaggle.  The part with which I'm struggling is a series of functions, in which the output of one becomes the input of the next.

Specifically, in the code provided, the function "word_token" takes the input "phraselist", tokenizes it, and returns a tokenized document titled "phrasedocs".  The only problem is that it doesn't seem to be working, because when I take that theoretical document "phrasedocs" and enter it into the next function, "process_token", I get:

NameError: name 'phrasedocs' is not defined

I am completely willing to accept that there is something simple I have overlooked, but I've been on this for hours and I can't figure it out.  I would appreciate any help.

I have tried proofreading and debugging the code, but my Python expertise is not great.

```
# This function obtains data from train.tsv

def processkaggle(dirPath, limitStr):
    # Convert the limit argument from a string to an int
    limit = int(limitStr)
    os.chdir(dirPath)
    f = open('./train.tsv', 'r')
    # Loop over lines in the file and use their first limit
    phrasedata = []
    for line in f:
        # Ignore the first line starting with Phrase, then read all lines
        if (not line.startswith('Phrase')):
            # Remove final end of line character
            line = line.strip()
            # Each line has four items, separated by tabs
            # Ignore the phrase and sentence IDs, keep the phrase and sentiment
            phrasedata.append(line.split('\t')[2:4])
    return phrasedata


# Randomize and subset data

def random_phrase(phrasedata):
    random.shuffle(phrasedata) # phrasedata initiated in function processkaggle
    phraselist = phrasedata[:limit]
    for phrase in phraselist[:10]:
        print(phrase)
    return phraselist


# Tokenization

def word_token(phraselist):
    phrasedocs=[]
    for phrase in phraselist:
        tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(phrase[0])
        phrasedocs.append((tokens, int(phrase[1])))
    return phrasedocs


# Pre-processing

# Convert all tokens to lower case
def lower_case(doc):
    return [w.lower() for w in doc]

# Clean text, fixing confusion over apostrophes
def clean_text(doc):
    cleantext=[]
    for review_text in doc:
        review_text = re.sub(r"it 's", "it is", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"that 's", "that is", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"\'s", "\'s", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"\'ve", "have", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"wo n't", "will not", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"do n't", "do not", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"ca n't", "can not", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"sha n't", "shall not", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"n\'t", "not", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"\'re", "are", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"\'d", "would", review_text)
        review_text = re.sub(r"\'ll", "will", review_text)
        cleantext.append(review_text)
    return cleantext

# Remove punctuation and numbers
def rem_no_punct(doc):
    remtext = []
    for text in doc:
        punctuation = re.compile(r'[-_.?!/\%@,":;\'{}<>~`()|0-9]')
        word = punctuation.sub("", text)
        remtext.append(word)
    return remtext

# Remove stopwords
def rem_stopword(doc):
    stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
    updatestopwords = [word for word in stopwords if word not in ['not','no','can','has','have','had','must','shan','do','should','was','were','won','are','cannot','does','ain','could','did','is','might','need','would']]
    return [w for w in doc if not w in updatestopwords]

# Lemmatization
def lemmatizer(doc):
    wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemma = [wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in doc]
    return lemma

# Stemming
def stemmer(doc):
    porter = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    stem = [porter.stem(t) for t in doc]
    return stem

# This function combines all the previous pre-processing functions into one, which is helpful
#   if I want to alter these settings for experimentation later

def process_token(phrasedocs):
    phrasedocs2 = []
    for phrase in phrasedocs:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(phrase[0])
        tokens = lower_case(tokens)
        tokens = clean_text(tokens)
        tokens = rem_no_punct(tokens)
        tokens = rem_stopword(tokens)
        tokens = lemmatizer(tokens)
        tokens = stemmer(tokens)
        phrasedocs2.append((tokens, int(phrase[1]))) # Any words that pass through the processing
                                                        # steps above are added to phrasedocs2
    return phrasedocs2


dirPath = 'C:/Users/J/kagglemoviereviews/corpus'
processkaggle(dirPath, 5000) # returns 'phrasedata'
random_phrase(phrasedata) # returns 'phraselist'
word_token(phraselist) # returns 'phrasedocs'
process_token(phrasedocs) # returns phrasedocs2


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-595bc4dcf121> in <module>()
      5 random_phrase(phrasedata) # returns 'phraselist'
      6 word_token(phraselist) # returns 'phrasedocs'
----> 7 process_token(phrasedocs) # returns phrasedocs2
      8 
      9 

NameError: name 'phrasedocs' is not defined
```

Comment: You never defined it.

Comment: You never assigned anything to the name `phrasedocs`.

Comment: I just assumed that when I ran a function, it would define the variable contained therein and assign it the value given by the "return" command.  I suck at Python, which is why I keep trying to use it like R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you defined "phrasedocs" inside a function which is not seen from outside and the function return should be captured in a variable, 
edit your code:

```
dirPath = 'C:/Users/J/kagglemoviereviews/corpus'
phrasedata = processkaggle(dirPath, 5000) # returns 'phrasedata'
phraselist = random_phrase(phrasedata) # returns 'phraselist'
phrasedocs = word_token(phraselist) # returns 'phrasedocs'
phrasedocs2 = process_token(phrasedocs) # returns phrasedocs2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only created the variable phrasedocs in a function. Therefore the variable is not defined for all of your other code outside this function. When you call the variable as an input to the function python can't find any variable named like that. You must create a variable called phrasedocs in your main code.